# How to convert a list of numbers to unique pairs of two

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have a situation where I need to convert a random array of whole numbers of an unknown length, to multiple pairs of 2.

Ex:

```js
var numbers = [1, 5, 0, 7, 5, 5, 1, 7, 5, 1, 2, 1];

-----------------------------------------------------
[[1, 5], [0, 7], [5, 5], [1, 7], [5, 1], [2, 1]]
```

There are a few constraints that need to follow, such as:

- There should be exactly 6 pairs (each of 2 numbers).
- If there aren't enough numbers in the `numbers` array to make 6 pairs, then generate a number that is between 1-9.
- Each item in the `numbers` array can be used only once.
- Each pair must be unique. But e.g `[1,2]` and `[2,1]` can be considered different pairs.
- A pair cannot contain `[0, 0]`

So far, I found a function that can find combinations but it does not ignore an index once it has already used it.

```js
var numbers = [1, 5, 0, 7, 5, 5, 1, 7, 5, 1, 2, 1];

function p(t, i) {
  if (t.length === 2) {
    result.push(t);
    return;
  }
  if (i + 1 > numbers.length) {
    return;
  }

  p(t.concat(numbers[i]), i + 1);
  p(t, i + 1);
}

var result = [];
p([], 0);
console.log(result);
```

What should I do next?

Comment: how do you generate the random numbers?

Comment: using Math.Random(), a number between 1-9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although [Nina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1447675/nina-scholz) may be right about OP needing only the first N pairs from an Array of unknown length, here's an extra check for it (and a slightly different approach to the problem):

```js
const nums1 = [1, 5, 0, 7, 5, 5, 1, 7, 1, 5, 1, 5];
const nums2 = [1, 5, 0, 7, 5, 5, 1, 7, 5, 1, 2, 1];
const nums3 = [1, 5, 0, 7, 5, 5, 0, 0, 5, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 8];
const nums4 = [1, 5, 0, 7, 1, 6, 5, 5, 0, 0, 5, 8, 8, 5, 5, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 8];
const log = pairs => console.log(JSON.stringify(pairs));
log(createPairs(nums1, 6));
log(createPairs(nums2, 6));
log(createPairs(nums3, 6));
log(createPairs(nums4, 5));
log(createPairs(nums4, 5, true));

function createPairs(numbers, len, truncate) {
  let pairs = [];
  let i = 0;
  const existingValues = new Set(['0|0']);
  const randomDigit = n => Math.floor(Math.random() * (n + 1));

  // create and complete array of [len] unique pairs, not being [0, 0]
  while (pairs.length < len) {
    const pair = i + 2 <= numbers.length
      ? numbers.slice(i, i += 2) 
      : [randomDigit(9), randomDigit(9)];
    const pairStr = pair.join(`|`);
    !existingValues.has(pairStr) && pairs.push(pair);
    existingValues.add(pairStr);
  }
  
  return i + 2 < numbers.length && !truncate 
    ? `This would deliver more pairs than desired (${len})` 
    : pairs;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: This code is much closer to what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could take some loops, one for checking the lenght of the result set, one for checking if there a values available of `array` and add values for taking the next pair and check if the pair has seen before.

If not add the pair to the result set and continue.

```js
var getRandomN = n => () => Math.floor(Math.random() * n) + 1,
    getRandom = getRandomN(9),
    array = [1, 5, 0, 7],
    seen = new Set(['0|0']),
    length = 6,                        // specify wanted length
    result = [],
    i = 0,
    pair;

while (result.length < length) {       // check result with wanted length
    do {
        while (array.length < i + 2) { // check if a pair is available
            array.push(getRandom());   // if not add new random value
        }
        pair = array.slice(i, i += 2); // get a pair and increment index
    } while (seen.has(pair.join('|'))) // repeat if a pair has seen before

    seen.add(pair.join('|'));          // add a fresh pair to the set
    result.push(pair);                 // take the pair for result
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you Nina, could you add a few comments to the lines. I would love to understand what is going on inside the loop.

Comment: Hi Nina, your code _will_ return `[0, 0]`-values within the result, which may be circumvented using `seen = new Set(['0|0']),`

Comment: Also, it will clip longer arrays like `[[1,5],[0,7],[1,6],[5,5],[5,8],[8,5],[5,1],[2,1]]` to `length` which is possibly not the desired result ;)

Comment: op wants only 6 pairs.

Comment: But does OP wants the first 6 pairs?

Comment: yes, the given numbers should be taken first, if not duiplicates, and if there are not enought, some random values.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I really like your solution, but you should know that your `getRandomN`-method never returns `0`

Comment: @KooiInc, op wants 1-9, please reads the comments under the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var numbers = [1, 5, 0, 7, 5, 5, 1, 7, 5, 1, 2, 1];
var arr = [];
numbers.forEach(function (x, i) {
  if(i % 2) {
    arr[arr.length-1][1] = x;
    console.log(arr[arr.length-1]);
  }
  else {
    arr.push([x, null]);
  }
});
console.log(arr.join("#"));
```

Comment: Please explain your answer.